# Beta regression with two groups

Tags: r, matrix

I'm attempting a beta regression on a data set with two groups (control and case).

```
           Normal.01 Normal.05 Normal.11 Normal.15 Normal.18 Normal.20 Normal.21 Normal.22 Normal.24 Normal.57
cg00000029   0.32605   0.28981   0.25767   0.26599   0.29924   0.27242   0.22222   0.28861   0.43764   0.26827
cg00000108   0.89785   0.89931   0.90689   0.89893   0.89284   0.90849   0.89940   0.89895   0.89720   0.91092
cg00000109   0.73910   0.72506   0.77163   0.75909   0.75974   0.76260   0.72887   0.80707   0.82701   0.73839
cg00000165   0.30960   0.29963   0.27489   0.30317   0.33740   0.27898   0.25004   0.42462   0.35888   0.30372
cg00000236   0.80654   0.81649   0.83556   0.81778   0.83017   0.84248   0.80569   0.86252   0.78328   0.81349
cg00000289   0.60874   0.62527   0.66264   0.71451   0.69799   0.68689   0.69102   0.61141   0.65301   0.66338
cg00000292   0.63333   0.69221   0.65881   0.64388   0.67124   0.69975   0.65229   0.63081   0.77145   0.62670
cg00000321   0.29422   0.34968   0.30429   0.30094   0.34405   0.29393   0.32035   0.30959   0.52361   0.28215
cg00000363   0.31460   0.27089   0.23656   0.23853   0.26131   0.18052   0.22021   0.35100   0.36632   0.23289
cg00000622   0.02190   0.03480   0.02973   0.03370   0.03124   0.03501   0.03951   0.02815   0.02684   0.03465
```

The first 10 columns are the control and the last 62 columns are case.

Below is an attempt at the beta regression:

```
group<-c(rep(0,10),rep(1,62))

group<-t(group)
n<-dim(beta_values)[1]
x<-cbind(beta_values[,1:10], beta_values[,11:72])

pvalues<-rep(0,n)

for(i in 1:n){

  model<-betareg(as.matrix(x[i,])~as.factor(group))
  pvalues[i]<-summary(model)$coefficients$mean[2,4]

}
```

Error message I am receiving:

```
    Error in model.frame.default(terms(formula, lhs = lhs, rhs = rhs, data = data,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'as.factor(group)')
```

Data set I am working with:

ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE37nnn/GSE37754/suppl/GSE37754_non-normalized.txt.gz

Edit:

First two rows of x:

```
           Normal.01 Normal.05 Normal.11 Normal.15 Normal.18 Normal.20 Normal.21 Normal.22 Normal.24 Normal.57 Tumor.01
cg00000029   0.32605   0.28981   0.25767   0.26599   0.29924   0.27242   0.22222   0.28861   0.43764   0.26827  0.58762
cg00000108   0.89785   0.89931   0.90689   0.89893   0.89284   0.90849   0.89940   0.89895   0.89720   0.91092  0.92337
           Tumor.02 Tumor.03 Tumor.04 Tumor.05 Tumor.06 Tumor.07 Tumor.08 Tumor.09 Tumor.10 Tumor.11 Tumor.12 Tumor.14
cg00000029  0.24012  0.22941  0.21687  0.21251  0.31149  0.44732  0.29103  0.25807  0.36930  0.34509  0.51639  0.65543
cg00000108  0.92256  0.92709  0.92221  0.89395  0.91425  0.91898  0.89680  0.91437  0.89951  0.89193  0.90456  0.90954
           Tumor.16 Tumor.17 Tumor.18 Tumor.19 Tumor.20 Tumor.21 Tumor.23 Tumor.24 Tumor.25 Tumor.26 Tumor.27 Tumor.28
cg00000029  0.17606  0.35455  0.18167  0.28175  0.23622  0.46089  0.29058  0.26638  0.44190  0.31124  0.43802  0.28132
cg00000108  0.90690  0.90970  0.90603  0.91548  0.90875  0.91662  0.91056  0.88788  0.91078  0.91458  0.90931  0.89668
           Tumor.29 Tumor.30 Tumor.31 Tumor.32 Tumor.33 Tumor.34 Tumor.35 Tumor.36 Tumor.38 Tumor.39 Tumor.41 Tumor.42
cg00000029  0.24104  0.38091  0.27517  0.37003  0.29224  0.32397  0.23482  0.22016  0.37136  0.29407  0.24363  0.34096
cg00000108  0.91568  0.87454  0.90568  0.89252  0.91243  0.90080  0.91220  0.87859  0.89292  0.87183  0.90030  0.90473
           Tumor.43 Tumor.44 Tumor.45 Tumor.46 Tumor.47 Tumor.48 Tumor.49 Tumor.50 Tumor.51 Tumor.52 Tumor.54 Tumor.55
cg00000029  0.35800  0.52592  0.45570  0.16679  0.43216  0.18037  0.34484  0.33328  0.32530  0.12381  0.45205  0.35937
cg00000108  0.91372  0.91950  0.91158  0.90271  0.90735  0.92654  0.92322  0.89788  0.88194  0.90243  0.91378  0.91552
           Tumor.58 Tumor.60 Tumor.61 Tumor.62 Tumor.63 Tumor.64 Tumor.65 Tumor.66 Tumor.67 Tumor.68 Tumor.69 Tumor.72
cg00000029  0.20225  0.37377  0.29465  0.55278  0.43761  0.39908  0.28128  0.31136  0.23631  0.28696  0.48497  0.34235
cg00000108  0.92908  0.90524  0.87337  0.90268  0.91282  0.91337  0.92986  0.92723  0.89658  0.86407  0.91670  0.91082
           Tumor.73
cg00000029  0.26999
cg00000108  0.90307
```

Comment: what do you get if you run: `length(as.matrix(x[1,]))==length(as.factor(group))`?

Comment: @SRivero It says TRUE

Comment: Could you please post the first rows of the `x` object?

Comment: I added the first two rows of the x object at the bottom of the original question.